# When using google analytics my cookies are reset

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I've begun using google analytics to just track the visitors that my website is receiving. But when I insert the code into the head file, my dark mode cookie is reset, and only when I remove all of the code and a hard deletion of all of the cookies does dark mode work again. I have not idea why this is  happening, and has this ever happened to you as well?

Comment: GA sets the cookie named _ga as well as a few other possible cookies similar to that. If your dark mode uses the same cookie name then that would be exact behavior to expect.  You can do more debugging to find out the reason and share your results here.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.